Optimized data structure mapping finite set of integers to values in C++
I'm looking for a mapping data structure, but knowing that the possible values of my keys are small numbers, I would like to trade memory for better performances (for both random access and value iteration).
It seems std::map and std::unordered_map aren't optimized for my use case. Therefore, I tried to come up with my own solution.
The idea is very simple: a first std::array serves as a lookup table toward addresses within another std::array that stores initialized values in sequence.
Inserting and accessing elements is therefore O(1) and iteration is optimized since values are stored contiguously in memory.
Here is the code with an usage example:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename K>
struct Iterator;

template <typename T, size_t N, typename K = size_t>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    MyContainer(const T &defaultValue)
    {
        m_values.fill({0, defaultValue});
        m_lookUpTable.fill(nullptr);
    }

    T &operator[](const K key)
    {
        auto &ptr = m_lookUpTable[key];
        if (ptr == nullptr)
        {
            ptr = &m_values[m_size++];
            ptr->first = key;
        }
        return ptr->second;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    Iterator<T, K> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<T, K>(m_values.data());
    }

    Iterator<T, K> end()
    {
        return Iterator<T, K>(m_values.data() + m_size);
    }

private:
    size_t m_size{0};
    std::array<std::pair<K, T>, N> m_values;
    std::array<std::pair<K, T> *, N> m_lookUpTable;
};

template <typename T, typename K>
struct Iterator
{
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::pair<K, T>;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    using reference = value_type &;

    Iterator(pointer pointer) : m_pointer(pointer) {}

    reference operator*() const { return *m_pointer; }

    pointer operator->() { return m_pointer; }

    Iterator &operator++()
    {
        m_pointer++;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int)
    {
        Iterator temp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }

    Iterator &operator--()
    {
        m_pointer--;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator--(int)
    {
        Iterator temp = *this;
        --(*this);
        return temp;
    }

    Iterator operator+(difference_type offset) const
    {
        return Iterator(m_pointer + offset);
    }

    Iterator &operator+=(difference_type offset)
    {
        m_pointer += offset;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator-(difference_type offset) const
    {
        return Iterator(m_pointer - offset);
    }

    Iterator &operator-=(difference_type offset)
    {
        m_pointer -= offset;
        return *this;
    }

    difference_type operator-(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer - other.m_pointer;
    }

    reference operator[](difference_type index) const
    {
        return m_pointer[index];
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer == other.m_pointer;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer != other.m_pointer;
    }

    bool operator<(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer < other.m_pointer;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer <= other.m_pointer;
    }

    bool operator>(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer > other.m_pointer;
    }

    bool operator>=(const Iterator &other) const
    {
        return m_pointer >= other.m_pointer;
    }

private:
    pointer m_pointer;
};

int main()
{
    // Random input data in the range [0, 365].
    std::vector<int> birthdays{{15, 290, 110, 1, 300, 40, 15, 111, 110, 200, 40, 11, 111, 110, 233, 87, 1, 29, 110}};

    MyContainer<int, 365> calendar(0);

    for (const auto day : birthdays)
    {
        calendar[day]++;
    }

    for (const auto &[key, val] : calendar)
    {
        std::cout << "Day " << key << " has " << val << " birthday(s).\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

My concerns are as follows:

I have no idea what to name my container. Is it a map? An array? A lookup table?
It follows from the previous point: it's a trivial structure, and yet I can't find any examples of it. If possible, I'd like to re-use an existing library rather than reinvent the wheel.
Can this data structure be improved in term of performances?
Is it possible for the iterator to produce std::pair<const K, T> without introducing UB and compromising performances?


I don’t know why this was downvoted either, and I will write you up a review, but for the meantime, I should point out that the answer to your first point is flat_map. Although, yours is more of an “in-place flat map”, I suppose.

Design review
You are massively over-complicating the problem
You call it a map, and you talk about using integers as keys. But… in reality, because your keys are small, you are just using indices. So what you want is really just a simple array, and a way to keep track of which indices are “active”.
Let me show you what I mean.
This is your example program. It prints every day of the year that has at least one birthday, and the number of birthdays.
Now, this is a rewrite of your example program, where I have replaced your “map” type with… a simple std::array. Obviously I had to change some stuff, because your type’s iterators return a pair, while std::array’s iterators return a single value. But literally all I had to do was add a views::enumerate to recreate the “key” and get a “key-value pair”, and a filter to not print days with zero birthdays (that is, filtering out the “inactive” items). And look, I get the same output, except just in a different order. (And, incidentally, your version is wrong, because associative containers should return the results in order. See for yourself.)
Granted, I’m simplifying a bit, because what you really want is an array and some way to keep track of which indices are “active” (so you don’t need the filter). So, basically, a type with an array, plus a bitset of flags.
(Or if the order that types were added matters, then you need a second array or vector to keep track of that. But that would be silly, because it doesn’t make sense for the order that types were created to matter.)
No interface
If you are making a container, the most important thing you should do is follow the standard container interface. If you don’t do that, your container is, at least, difficult to use, and, in practice, mostly useless.
In your case, you are making an associative container, so you should be trying to conform to the standard associative container interface. As you can see, there is quite a lot there, but you don’t need to support everything. Obviously if something just doesn’t apply to your container, you don’t include that.
However, your type has an extremely minimal interface… so minimal that I would say it’s generally useless. Maybe it works for the one specific use case you have in mind, but it is definitely not a general-use type.
For example… I can “add” items to the map (sorta)… but how would I remove an item from the map? Currently the only way I can think to do that is to:

Create a whole new empty map.
Loop over the elements of the existing map.
a.  If the key/value is what I want to remove, do nothing.
b.  Otherwise, copy it to the new map.
Copy the new map over the old map.

Which is bonkers. (And won’t work, due to bugs that we’ll get to.)
Don’t separate iterators from their containers
The type Iterator is completely meaningless on its own. It should be associated with the container… but it’s not; it’s a completely independent type.
In fact, I could do this:
auto p = std::pair<int, double>{0, 0.0};
auto it = Iterator<int, double>{&p};    // whut?

That’s right, I can create an “iterator to a random pair”… not even a container, not even a sequence of pairs, just a random pair somewhere in memory.
Iterator should be a nested type within Container… and it should not be possible to construct iterators outside of a container (except that iterators should be default constructible—which yours is not—and incidentally it should be named iterator, not Iterator).
So, something more like this:
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename K = std::size_t>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        using iterator_concept  = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type      = std::pair<K, T>;

        using pointer   = value_type *;
        using reference = value_type &;

        constexpr iterator() noexcept = default;

    private:
        constexpr explicit iterator(pointer pointer) noexcept
            : m_pointer(pointer)
        {}

        pointer m_pointer = nullptr;

        friend class MyContainer;
    };

    // ...
};

Note that you will also need const_iterator… and no, const_iterator is NOT just const iterator.
Concerns raised
What to name container
It is a map.
Searching for existing library rather reinventing wheel
It is literally impossible for anyone to suggest any existing library to do what you need done, for the simple reason that you have not said what you need done.
Improved performance?
You should really be worrying about correctness before you start worrying about performance. Because, spoiler alert, this type is very dangerous to use, and very easy to break. Indeed, it is positively riddled with bugs.
Possible for the iterator to produce std::pair<const K, T> without introducing UB and compromising performances?
Yes, trivially.
template <typename T, typename K>
struct Iterator
{
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::pair<const K, T>;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator(pointer pointer) : m_pointer(pointer) {}

    reference operator*() const { return _val; }

    pointer operator->() { return &_val; }

    Iterator &operator++()
    {
        m_pointer++;
        _val = *m_pointer;
        return *this;
    }

    // ... and so on...

private:
    pointer m_pointer;
    std::pair<const K, T> _val;
};

This isn’t the only way to do it, and I’ve glossed over some complications (T with no default construct? end iterator dereferencing?), but that’s the gist. (A better solution might be to hold an optional of the value type, and only engage it when dereferenced. But, again, that’s the gist.)
But, I mean, you could just rethink the problem. The only reason you want keys to be non-const is because you are making them disordered. You could simply initialize the array to {{0, defaultValue}, {1, defaultValue}, ...}, and keep track of which indices are “active”. Then the key value would never need to change.
Code review
There is no namespace. All of your code should be in a namespace. Polluting the global namespace is bad manners.
namespace delgan is a good choice.
template <typename T, typename K>
struct Iterator;

This should not be an independent class. It has no meaning outside of the container. And, as it is, there is no association between the container and iterator.
template <typename T, size_t N, typename K = size_t>
class MyContainer

So, first, there is no such type as size_t. It is std::size_t, and you have to include the proper header.
Your code only appears to be working now due to historical quirks. In the not-too-distant future, that will no longer be true.
Now, I am completely baffled as to why you have allowed the key type to be a template parameter. What else could it possibly be, other than std::size_t? It must be convertible from 0 (cf the constructor), and it must be convertible to std::size_t (cf the indexing operation in the brackets operator). So it has to be some kind of integer, and it should be unsigned (to avoid conversion weirdness from negative values).
I suppose it is possible in theory to use unsigned int or unsigned short or something like that, but… why? Why allow that? It doesn’t really open many new options, but it does create new risks.
In any case, these template parameters need some constraining. K must be std::unsigned_integral. (And, really, should only be std::size_t.) T has to be at least default initializable and copyable (you can’t make your internal array otherwise). That would imply it should be std::semiregular.
    MyContainer(const T &defaultValue)
    {
        m_values.fill({0, defaultValue});
        m_lookUpTable.fill(nullptr);
    }

Okay, there’s quite a bit wrong here.
For starters, single-argument constructors should almost always be explicit. Because you have not done that, your container is now constructible from whatever type it holds. For example:
auto func(MyContainer<std::string, 10> const&);

func("whut?");

Next up, const T &defaultValue is not how we write C++. In C++, we keep the type and type modifiers together. In other words:

const T &defaultValue: this is C-style
const T& defaultValue: this is C++-style
T const& defaultValue: also C++-style

Now, let’s get to the meat of the problem. Your primary concern appears to be efficiency (so much so that it even appears to trump functionality). Yet this type is horribly inefficient in many places, most of which are due to the use of std::array.
std::array is not an efficient type. std::vector beats it in almost every practical use case, once you account for dynamic allocation. And that is irrelevant here, because you know up front­—even at compile time, apparently—what the maximum size is going to be. So you can just reserve the memory up front, and never need to allocate again. With no allocation costs, std::vector will generally beat the pants off of std::array.
With std::array, your costs to copy or move are linear. With std::vector, the copy costs are still linear, but in practice you can avoid most copies and just always move… and vector moves are super fast.
With both std::array and std::vector, your construction costs will be heavy, because both need to initialize the entire array. std::vector also has to do an allocation, so it appears std::array is the winner. Except… you only construct an object once… but you may move it around many times. And there is just no contest here; vector moves are way faster than array “moves”.
So, here’s the bottom line: You care about performance? std::array sucks. std::vector will almost always beat it many times over, in real-world, practical use. Yes, std::vector has to allocate while std::array does not, but even with that, std::vector still outperforms std::array when viewed holistically, for practical use cases.
    T &operator[](const K key)
    {
        auto &ptr = m_lookUpTable[key];
        if (ptr == nullptr)
        {
            ptr = &m_values[m_size++];
            ptr->first = key;
        }
        return ptr->second;
    }

Okay, this is the meat of the entire code base, and it is were most of the problems show up.
The major problem with this type is that it uses pointers into itself to keep track of stuff. That is a terrible idea.
Just consider what happens here:
auto a = new MyContainer<std::string, 4>{"foo"};

// So:
//  a->m_values      = {{0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a->m_lookUpTable = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}

(*a)[2] = "bar";    // This line sets a->m_values[0] to {2, "bar"},
                    // and a->m_lookUpTable[2] to &(a->m_values[0])

// So now:
//  a.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a.m_lookUpTable = {nullptr, nullptr, &(a->m_values[0]), nullptr}

auto b = a; // Copy construction.

// So now:
//  a->m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a->m_lookUpTable = {nullptr, nullptr, &(a->m_values[0]), nullptr}
//
//  b.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  b.m_lookUpTable = {nullptr, nullptr, &(a->m_values[0]), nullptr}
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// !!!!!!!! DO YOU SEE THE PROBLEM? !!!!!!!!

delete a;

// So now:
//  *a no longer exists
//
//  b.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  b.m_lookUpTable = {nullptr, nullptr, &(a->m_values[0]), nullptr}
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Yup.
Basically, if you are going to keep pointers to parts of an object:

you can NEVER move or copy that object; or
you have to be very careful to change the pointers as the object is moved/copied around, so they stay in sync.

Generally, you should never keep pointers to internal data. It’s just too easy to break. One good alternative is to use indices instead. Let’s imagine that instead of an array of pointers, m_lookUpTable is an array of indices, and re-run the same code:
auto a = new MyContainer<std::string, 4>{"foo"};

// So:
//  a->m_values      = {{0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a->m_lookUpTable = {-1, -1, -1, -1}

(*a)[2] = "bar";    // This line sets a->m_values[0] to {2, "bar"},
                    // and a->m_lookUpTable[2] to 0

// So now:
//  a.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a.m_lookUpTable = {-1, -1, 0, -1}

auto b = a; // Copy construction.

// So now:
//  a->m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  a->m_lookUpTable = {-1, -1, 0, -1}
//
//  b.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  b.m_lookUpTable = {-1, -1, 0, -1}

delete a;

// So now:
//  *a no longer exists
//
//  b.m_values      = {{3, "bar"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}, {0, "foo"}}
//  b.m_lookUpTable = {-1, -1, 0, -1}

// b is still okay!

I’ll have to stop the review here, because I’ve run out of time, but I’ll leave you with an alternative design to chew on:
Alternative design
// Just bashing this code out quickly, probably won’t compile...

template <std::semiregular T, std::size_t N>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    using key_type    = std::size_t;
    using mapped_type = T;

    using key_compare = std::less<key_type>;

    using value_type = std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>;

    using pointer       = value_type*;
    using const_pointer = value_type const*;

    using reference       = value_type&;
    using const_reference = value_type const&;

    using iterator       = value_type*;
    using const_iterator = value_type const*;

    using reverse_iterator       = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using size_type       = std::size_t;

    constexpr explicit MyContainer(T const& defaultValue)
        : MyContainer{defaultValue, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}}
    {}

    constexpr auto operator[](key_type i) -> mapped_type&
    {
        _active.set(i);
        return _data[i].second;
    }

    constexpr auto size()  const noexcept { return _active.count(); }
    constexpr auto empty() const noexcept { return _active.none(); }

    constexpr auto begin() const& noexcept { return _data.begin(); }
    constexpr auto begin()      & noexcept { return _data.begin(); }
    constexpr auto end()   const& noexcept { return _data.end(); }
    constexpr auto end()        & noexcept { return _data.end(); }

    constexpr auto cbegin() const& noexcept { return _data.cbegin(); }
    constexpr auto cend()   const& noexcept { return _data.cend(); }

    constexpr auto clear() { _active.reset(); }

    constexpr auto count(key_type i) const noexcept { return _active[i] ? 1uz : 0uz; }

    constexpr auto find(key_type i) const& noexcept { return _active[i] ? (begin() + i) : end(); }
    constexpr auto find(key_type i)      & noexcept { return _active[i] ? (begin() + i) : end(); }

    constexpr auto contains(key_type i) const noexcept { return _active[i]; }

    // ... and so on ...

private:
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr MyContainer(T const& defaultValue, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : _data{{Is, defaultValue}...}
    {}

    std::array<value_type, N> _data;
    std::bitset<N>            _active;
};

I implemented a couple of member functions there, hopefully the rest should be obvious from there. There is a lot of extra complexity I didn’t bother to illustrate.
But the key idea should be clear. Your data is stored in an array of pair<size_t const, T>, and you have a bitset<N> that keeps track of which items are “active”. Whenever you add an item with key i to the map, you set _active.set(i). Whenever you remove an item, you do _active.reset(i). Everything else is gravy.
Note that this is only one alternative. Another alternative would be to use a vector, not an array, and instead of a bitset have an array of indices into that vector. This would allow you to avoid constructing any elements until they are actually added to the map. It would require some extra work to make sure the index array stays valid when elements are added and removed to the vector… but shouldn’t be too hard. And it would probably be a lot more efficient for most uses.
Good luck!

+1 for emphasising interface by mentioning it early. I'd add that without a standard one, the code isn't maintainable for lack of documentation.

(doesn't input data in the range [0, 365] call for 366 (this being a leap year)?)

Thank you for this tremendous answer. Apologies, I now understand my code was definitely not ready for review, it was more of a proof of concept. I'll know for next time. Additionally, as you said, I wasn't specific enough about the use case such structure could be good for, which doesn't help. In the meantime, I discovered this article which enumerates a few possible implementations. In any case, I learned a lot from this review, thanks!

I contend that the correct name for "array, with some elements missing/skipped" is "sparse array", "sparse vector", or "sparse matrix".

range check
There's no provision for validating key against N,
not even in a debug build.
    T &operator[](const K key)
    {
        auto &ptr = m_lookUpTable[key];

The Public API you've designed impresses me as being
too easy for a caller to accidentally misuse, leading to
UB.
I will observe that the client code looks lovely,
very compact and expressive.
Defining the various comparison operators is tedious; I have
to assume that C++23 somewhere offers a template for such chores.
class name

what to name my container ...
... find any examples of it

It's a map.
It shares some design aspects of the
dict
internal datastructure.

improved in term of performances?

We allocate N array elements for m_size entries,
with an efficiency ratio of m_size / N.
You would do well to study the efficiency tradeoffs
made in python's dict datastructure, and see what you
can import into this setting.
